# App compiled in qt creator crashes

Tags: c++, openssl, qt-creator

I developed an app in qt creator (only working on windows) which uses openssl... the funny part is that outside qt creator the app crashes for a ntdll.dll problem or sleay32.dll...

The only way I found for fixing this is activating compatibility mode (windows 7) even if I'm running windows 7.

```
Application Version:    0.5.1.0
Application Timestamp:  53cf2797
Fault Module Name:  ntdll.dll
Fault Module Version:   6.2.9200.16578
Fault Module Timestamp: 515fac6e
Exception Code: c0000005
Exception Offset: 0006191c
OS Version: 6.2.9200.2.0.0.256.4
Locale ID:  1033
Additional Information 1:   5861
Additional Information 2:   5861822e1919d7c014bbb064c64908b2
Additional Information 3:   1a2a
Additional Information 4:   1a2aa8e38ac8adbb6fe1e594fa623c2e
```

Do you know how to fix this without activating compatibility mode?

Comment: Have your copied platforms\qwindows.dll into the directory with your .exe file?

Comment: It's most likely a bug in your application. A dangling pointer that's causing memory violation.

Comment: Perhaps you could provide more information, like a stack trace. Better, build a release version of your app without optimizations, and include symbols.

Comment: the problem is that when I run it in qt creator, it works just fine... but when I run the executable by my own is when the app crashes :S So I can't see the stack trace

Comment: I don't use QT, so I don't know what it provides. With that said, you should turn on any Debugging or Memory assistants available. Or, compile you code with Clang and use its memory sanitizer (`-fsanitize=address`).